# Hyperledger - Fabric Node SDK - Curve property error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hyperledger

I am facing problems when deploying a node project to Heroku.

Got a constant error that is from a dependency of `fabri-client` package.

The error is: `"Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined"`. It is not clear enough to me why.

All the generated files already was verified (cert files, pem and all configurations files). And it is exactly equals in production and local.

Seems to be an error about some file or property not being able to be read. I already looked a lot and found nothing about it.

`2018-10-08T13:13:24.139587+00:00 app[web.1]: [31merror[39m: [Client.js]: Failed to load user "admin" from local key value store. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139597+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10378)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139599+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:204:27)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139602+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139737+00:00 app[web.1]: [31merror[39m: [Client.js]: Failed to load an instance of requested user "admin" from the state store on this Client instance. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139740+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10378)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139742+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:204:27)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.139743+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-10-08T13:13:24.140035+00:00 app[web.1]: ERRO:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
2018-10-08T13:13:24.140037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10378)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.140039+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:204:27)
2018-10-08T13:13:24.140041+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-10-08T13:13:30.471688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/add_id" host=damp-lowlands-60646.herokuapp.com request_id=a13c1b5d-31f0-4e24-aabb-8733b102cf18 fwd="201.48.168.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=500 bytes=322 protocol=https
2018-10-08T13:13:30.463089+00:00 app[web.1]: [31merror[39m: [Client.js]: Failed to load user "admin" from local key value store. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
2018-10-08T13:13:30.463101+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10378)
2018-10-08T13:13:30.463103+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:204:27)
2018-10-08T13:13:30.463105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-10-08T13:13:30.466974+00:00 app[web.1]: [31merror[39m: [Client.js]: Failed to load an instance of requested user "admin" from the state store on this Client instance. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
2018-10-08T13:13:30.466978+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10378)
2018-10-08T13:13:30.466980+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:204:27)
2018-10-08T13:13:30.466982+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-10-08T13:13:30.468452+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to invoke successfully :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, What worked for me was the following

1. Make sure you are using the latest versions of "fabric-ca-client" and "fabric-client" in your package.json for the node modules (Basically it should match the version of fabric you are trying to connect to).
2. Use the latest version of invoke.js / query.js that is provided along with the sample application (fabcar) (There are some minor differences that are there in the newer version).

**NOTE:** In my case the issue came up because i was using the 1.3 version of the client code where as my hyperledger fabric was 1.4 version

Answer (score 0):

This is due to invalid/expired certificates in the fabric-client-kv-* folder.

Solution:

1. Delete or backup the contents of the fabric-client-kv-* folder.
2. Register Admin user again.
3. Register the normal user now.

If you cant find the certificate folder, look for the line bellow in your program,

```
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store');
```

or

```
  credentialStore:
    # [Optional]. Specific to FileKeyValueStore.js or similar implementations in other SDKs. Can be others
    # if using an alternative impl. For instance, CouchDBKeyValueStore.js would require an object
    # here for properties like url, db name, etc.
    path: "./fabric-client-kv-org1"
```

"hfc-key-store" or "fabric-client-kv-org1" is the folder containing the certificates.